# Retrieve value from JSON and generate HTML to each register

Tags: javascript, php, json, cordova

I'm having a little bit of trouble on how to create a JQuery structure to append a HTML code to each of the items returned by my JSON. Basically my doubt is on how to retrieve each of the JSON values and put it on a repetition structure to create the code that, by the end, should be printed on the app screen. It's all quite simple code as I'm just learning how to work with phonegap, webservices and stuff. Thanks in advance.

Just to enlighten any doubt: I want to create a panel to each element that the request returns on the JSON. The panel should contain a soccer championship and it's country as in the hardcoded example below: [App Layout](https://s18.postimg.org/4igmme6o9/Captura_de_tela_de_2016_10_06_12_35_15.png)

**webservice.js**

```
function listaCampeonatos(){
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://localhost/projetos/centraljogos/webservice//listagem.php',
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {type:'listaCampeonatos'},
    ContentType: 'application/json',
    success: function(response){
        //alert('Listagem bem sucedida!');
        //$('#resultado').html(JSON.stringify(response));

        console.log(response);

        for (i=0 ; i<response.length ; i++){
            alert('Entrou no for');
            $('#resultado').html(response[i].nome_campeonato);
        }
    },
    error: function(err){
        alert('Ocorreu um erro ao se comunicar com o servidor! Por favor, entre em contato com o administrador ou tente novamente mais tarde.');
        console.log(err);
    }
});
```

}

**listagem.php**

```
include './conexao.php';

header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");

$link = conectar();

if ($_GET['type'] == "listaCampeonatos") {
    //echo 'Tipo de operação: ' . $_GET['type'] . '<br>';

    $query = "SELECT c.id AS id_campeonato, c.nome_camp AS nome_campeonato, p.nome_pais AS nome_pais
                  FROM tb_campeonato c
                  LEFT JOIN  tb_pais p ON p.id = c.tb_pais_id
                  LEFT JOIN  tb_partida pt ON pt.tb_campeonato_id = c.id
                  WHERE pt.flag_ativo = 1

                  GROUP BY p.nome_pais";

    $result = mysqli_query($link, $query);

    $registros = array();

    while ($reg = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
        $registros[] = array('Campeonatos' => $reg);
    }

    $saida = json_encode(array('Lista' => $registros));

    echo $saida;
}
```

**jogos.html**

```
<!-- COTAÇÕES INÍCIO -->
    <div id="painel_partidas" class="panel panel-primary panel-heading-margin">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <center>
                <b>Brasil &raquo; Série A - 19/10/2016</b>
                <button data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#partida" class="btn btn-default btn-xs pull-right"><i class="fa fa-compress"></i></button>
            </center>
        </div>

        <div id="partida">
            <div class="w3-border">

                <center>
                    <button class="btn btn-xs btn-danger" onclick="listaCampeonatos()"><i class="fa fa-search"></i>
                    Testar JSON
                    </button>
                </center>

                <div id="resultado"></div>

                <!--COTAÇÕES AQUI-->

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- COTAÇÕES FIM -->
```

Comment: technically, you DON'T have json anymore. the json you got from the server was automatically decoded by jquery before calling`function(response)`, and what's in `response` is a plain old JS data structure, **NOT** json. You access the data in that like you would access data in any OTHER javascript data structure.

Comment: Right, that's what I'm trying to do right now. I've updated the question with the function. It appears that the function doesn't enter the 'for' since it doesn't show me the alert.

Comment: now you're doing a loop and continuously replacing the content of your one div on every loop iterating. if you want to dump ALL of that into `#resultado`, then you'd want `for(...) { text += response[...]} $('#resultado').html(text);`. Modify the dom ONCE once the loop's completed, not everyt ime.

Comment: Nevertheless it should  append the last element on the DOM, right? And I showl see the alert as well. I'm just testing here and it doesn't seem to modify the page.

Comment: does `console.log(response)` do anything?

Comment: Object {Lista: Array[2]}
Lista
:
Array[2]
0
:
Object
Campeonatos
:
Object
id_campeonato
:
"630"
nome_campeonato
:
"Copa do Mundo
"
nome_pais
:
"África
"
__proto__
:
Object
__proto__
:
Object
Object {Lista: Array[2]}
Lista
:
Array[2]
0
:
Object
Campeonatos
:
Object
id_campeonato
:
"630"
nome_campeonato
:
"Copa do Mundo
"
nome_pais
:
"África
"
__proto__
:
Object
__proto__
:
Object

Comment: That's the console.log(response)

Comment: so there you go. you're looping on the wrong thing. `response[i]` isn't one of your records, it's that `Lista` object. you have an array of an object of arrays of objects, basically.

Comment: And if I try $('#resultado').html(JSON.stringify(response)); I get:  

`{"Lista":[{"Campeonatos":{"id_campeonato":"630","nome_campeonato":"Copa do Mundo\r","nome_pais":"África\r"}},{"Campeonatos":{"id_campeonato":"11","nome_campeonato":"Série A\r","nome_pais":"Brasil\r"}}]}`

Comment: try `i <= response.lista.length` isntead, etc...

Comment: Oh!! I haven't thought about that. So what should the call of the object be? response.Lista.Campeonatos[ i ]?

Comment: it should EXACTLY match the structure you built in PHP, that's it. if you have an array of arrays in php, then you'll end up with an array of arrays in JS as well, though PHP arrays WILL get converted to JS objects, if you're using non-numeric keys, or non-sequential numeric keys.

Comment: All right, I can enter the 'for' now but still can't alert(response.Lista.Campeonatos.nome_campeonato[i]);

Answer (score 0):

Make some modifications in `listagem.php` as given below

```
 while ($reg = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
        $registros[] = $reg;
    }

    $saida = json_encode($registros);

    echo $saida;
```

Now you will be able to loop through the returned `response` object in `webservice.js`

```
 success: function(response){
        //alert('Listagem bem sucedida!');
        //$('#resultado').html(JSON.stringify(response));

        console.log(response);

        for (i=0 ; i<response.length ; i++){
            alert('Entrou no for');
            $('#resultado').html(response[i].nome_campeonato);
        }
    }
```

Do not use  `$('#resultado').html(response[i].nome_campeonato)` if you need all the values of `response[i].nome_campeonato` inside `<div id="resultado"></div>`.Instead use

```
$('#resultado').append(response[i].nome_campeonato +"<br>");
```